# PHP script running on cron job - email alert

Tags: php, joomla

I'm building a Joomla site, but I'm stuck at something, wondering if you guys could kindly help me out.

I'm trying to get an alerting system working.

I essentially need to create a cron job that runs a PHP script every 10 minutes. This PHP script should basically do a select query on the database, and if a particular field has a specific value, then open a website.

So, this is what I have now:

```
$result = mysql_connect(localhost, myusername, mypassword);
mysql_select_db("database_name");
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT from_table");
```

The table name is: comments.
The field name is: published.

So what I would ideally need, is that if the value of published = 0, then the php script should open this URL, which will send me an sms message https://www.voipbuster.com/myaccount/sendsms.php?username=xx&password=xx&from=xx&to=xx&text=Alert

And if there is any other value, I don't want it to do anything.

So, anytime there is value 0 I receive a text message.

Hope this makes sense, thanks for your immense patience reading.

Comment: You should probably try to do this yourself and come back with a specific question and a not a request for code. imo..

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) It sounds to me like you know how to do this, you just laid out the procedure in exact detail. Just translate you question, sentence by sentence, into code and you should end up with something pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get Andrew Eddie's script for cron plugins and run that. Then write a plugin in the cron group  that sends your email.
https://github.com/eddieajau/jc-kodaly

Answer (score 0):

Switch to PDO (or MySQLi). The API you're using is deprecated.

(based on nothing - this is a guess)

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$sql = 'SELECT published FROM sometable';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setAttribute(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $stmt->fetch();

if( $row['published'] == 0 )
{
    $ch = curl_init(" https://www.voipbuster.com/myaccount/sendsms.php?username=xx&password=xx&from=xx&to=xx&text=Alert");

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, I understand the logic but have spent the last two days on this trying to make it work with no success.

Comment: The server where I'm hosted is MYSQL, can't change to PDO or MySQLi unfortunately. ethrbunny there are no connection details on your code, how is that possible?

Comment: Whilst the code i earlier published may be deprecated, I have taken some security measures as .htaccess permissions on the php script folder as well as the mysql account used can only do select queries

Comment: Connection info added - my bad

Comment: Getting an error @ethrbunny

       Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username_at_database'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in /home/test.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /home/test.php(5): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'db_user', 'db_password') #1 {main} thrown in /home/test.php on line 5 `code`

line 5 is   $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=actual_db_name', $user, $pass); `code`

Comment: So: PDO is installed but the credentials you used weren't valid. Either you don't have 'localhost' login or name/pw were wrong.

Comment: ahhhhh, managed to get it to work... I had an error on the syntax, thanks so much, this is exactly what I needed